# Detecting when a text channel is created by another bot with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm pretty new to javascript or discord.js but my guess was something like this:

```
client.on('channelCreate', channel =>
{
    message.channel.send('test');
})
```

I'm guessing *'channelCreate'* doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is right.

According to the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.7.0/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelCreate), you can listen to a `channelCreate` event to trigger something when a channel is created.

To know who created a channel, your bot need to access the audit logs and the first entry of it.

```js
client.on("channelCreate", async (channel) => {
  if (!channel.guild) return;

  // Fetch the audit logs of CHANNEL_CREATE events.
  const audit_logs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
    limit: 1,
    type: "CHANNEL_CREATE"
  });

  if (!audit_logs.entries.first()) {
    console.error("No entry found.");
    return;
  }

  const entry = audit_logs.entries.first();
  const executor = entry.executor;

  // The executor property is type User,
  // so you can easily check if it's a bot by doing...
  const is_bot = executor.bot;

  // `is_bot` will be boolean.
});
```

### Resources

- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.7.0/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs
- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.7.0/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor
- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/13.7.0/class/User?scrollTo=bot